# No engine found - PredictionIO

Tags: scala, predictionio

No engine found error when using the below Scala template,
http://predictionio.incubator.apache.org/templates/complementarypurchase/quickstart/

I have the correct Scala version,

```
scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.8 -- Copyright 2002-2016, LAMP/EPFL
```

From template build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
```

Logs:

```
[INFO] [Engine$] [info] Done updating.
[INFO] [Engine$] [info] Compiling 5 Scala sources to /home/pioEngine/MyComplementaryPurchase/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[INFO] [Engine$] [info] Packaging /home/pioEngine/MyComplementaryPurchase/target/scala-2.11/template-scala-parallel-complementary-purchase_2.11-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[INFO] [Engine$] [info] Done packaging.
[INFO] [Engine$] [success] Total time: 25 s, completed Sep 29, 2017 5:03:02 PM
[INFO] [Engine$] [info] Including: scala-library-2.11.8.jar
[INFO] [Engine$] [info] Run completed in 127 milliseconds.
[INFO] [Engine$] [info] Total number of tests run: 0
[INFO] [Engine$] [info] Suites: completed 0, aborted 0
[INFO] [Engine$] [info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[INFO] [Engine$] [info] No tests were executed.
[INFO] [Engine$] [info] Checking every *.class/*.jar file's SHA-1.
[INFO] [Engine$] [info] Merging files...
[INFO] [Engine$] [warn] Merging 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' with strategy 'discard'
[INFO] [Engine$] [warn] Strategy 'discard' was applied to a file
[INFO] [Engine$] [info] SHA-1: 694c8171bc698f340ad43074d037fc26642ffa8d
[INFO] [Engine$] [info] Packaging /home/pioEngine/MyComplementaryPurchase/target/scala-2.11/template-scala-parallel-complementary-purchase-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT-deps.jar ...
[INFO] [Engine$] [info] Done packaging.
[INFO] [Engine$] [success] Total time: 3 s, completed Sep 29, 2017 5:03:04 PM
[INFO] [Engine$] Compilation finished successfully.
[INFO] [Engine$] Looking for an engine...
[ERROR] [Engine$] No engine found. Your build might have failed. Aborting.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem today. This post solved my problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/actionml-user/w9cHuRjBrO0

I hope it can help you :)

Comment: That worked, I am able to build successfully now. All I did was I created a directory scala-2.10 under /MyComplementaryPurchase/target. Then copied the dependencies from scala-2.11 to scala-2.10. Now when I execute "pio build", the dependencies are recognized and the build completes.

Comment: @Srini Running UR (build Scala 2.10) on PIO (build Scala 2.11) will create conflicts and your [training might fail](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/actionml-user/w9cHuRjBrO0/2lKLq2NVAQAJ). Try building both PIO and Engine Template (UR) on same Scala ver.